# Send a list of items

Tags: list, spring-mvc, arraylist

I have a form in Spring MVC where a list of users are entered via javascript. The problem is that I do not know how to pass the list to the server.

```
    <form:hidden path="var1" value="ex1"></form:hidden>
    <form:hidden path="var2" value="ex2"></form:hidden>
    <form:hidden path="var3" value="ex3"></form:hidden>
    <form:hidden path="var4" value="ex4"></form:hidden>
```

how do I put my list in an array or List of objects ?
I can not define every single variable because the list can consist of many objects.

Answer (score 2):

Keep the path same for all values

`<form:hidden path="var" value="ex1"></form:hidden>
 <form:hidden path="var" value="ex2"></form:hidden>
 <form:hidden path="var" value="ex3"></form:hidden>
 <form:hidden path="var" value="ex4"></form:hidden>`

Controller :

String[] arrVar = request.getParameterValues("var");

Comment: I badly explained myself. The problem is that I have to send a list of items